# SQLiteDatabase insert function returns -1

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have a database which is calling Medicine, there are four columns in it: id (primary key autoincrement), dId (foreign key), Name and Time. I try to add new row using insert function. This function must return id of this adding. But when I check this from debugger, I see that it returned -1.

Code:

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("RECIPE_ID", recipeId);
        values.put("MED_NAME", etMedName.getText().toString());
        values.put("MED_TIME", etMedTime.getText().toString());
        long mid = sqdb.insert("Medicine", null, values);
```

Comment: If the `recipeId` is `autoincrement`, you shouldn't put it in the `ContentValues`, right? Meanwhile, you don't include `dld` in your request, is that normal?

Comment: I want to put `recipeId` value to `dId`, which is foreign key. Primary key, `id`, is autoincrement, so I didn't put it in the `ContentValues`.

Comment: Got it. I guess you checked your field names, etc... ? Also, did you try using a raw query to be sure it works ? `insert` returns -1 when an error occurs, so there must be somthing wrong with your query

Comment: I found! I forgot that the keys should be a column names. Thank you!

Comment: @AskarZaitov use the method define in my answer it will tell you the probable Exceptions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
 long mid = 0;

try
    {
        mid = sqdb.insertOrThrow("Medicine", null, values);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        // Sep 12, 2013 6:50:17 AM
        Log.e("Exception","SQLException"+String.valueOf(e.getMessage()));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It will tell you the probable Exception

Comment: @AskarZaitov Yes i saw in your comment and also if you use this then you will get cached and will get your error if any this is recommended method

Comment: This helped me find the cause! Thanks! What's weird is with the "insert" method call, SQLite doesn't throw an exception by default and that you have to use "insertOrThrow" to get it to throw an exception.